# How to increase main-camera height for thirdpersoncontroller in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue whereby I am unable to uplift camera height to head of third-person controller, always it is in the middle of third-person controller. Could anyone help me on this regard.

[This is image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT2lw.png)

Here is the code attatched to my thirdpersoncontroller:

```
public class ThirdPersonCam : NetworkBehaviour
{

    public Transform cameraTransform;
    private Transform _target;

    // The distance in the x-z plane to the target

    public float distance = 2.0f;

    // the height we want the camera to be above the target
    public float height = 0.0f;

    public float angularSmoothLag = 0.0000001f;
    public float angularMaxSpeed = 100000000.0f;

    public float heightSmoothLag = 0.3f;

    public float snapSmoothLag = 0.2f;
    public float snapMaxSpeed = 720.0f;

    public float clampHeadPositionScreenSpace = 0.75f;

    public float lockCameraTimeout = 0.2f;

    private Vector3 headOffset = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 centerOffset = Vector3.zero;

    private float heightVelocity = 0.0f;
    private float angleVelocity = 0.0f;
    private bool snap = false;
    private ThirdPersonShooter controller;
    private float targetHeight = 100000.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (!cameraTransform && Camera.main)
            cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
        if (!cameraTransform)
        {
            Debug.Log("Please assign a camera to the ThirdPersonCamera script.");
            enabled = false;
        }

        _target = transform;
        if (_target)
        {
            controller = _target.GetComponent<ThirdPersonShooter>();
        }

        if (controller)
        {
            CharacterController characterController = _target.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            centerOffset = characterController.bounds.center - _target.position;
            headOffset = centerOffset;
            headOffset.y = characterController.bounds.max.y - _target.position.y;
        }
        else
            Debug.Log("Please assign a target to the camera that has a ThirdPersonController script attached.");

        Cut(_target, centerOffset);
    }

    void DebugDrawStuff()
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(_target.position, _target.position + headOffset);
    }

    public float AngleDistance(float a, float b)
    {
        a = Mathf.Repeat(a, 360);
        b = Mathf.Repeat(b, 360);

        return Mathf.Abs(b - a);
    }

    void Apply(Transform dummyTarget, Vector3 dummyCenter)
    {
        // Early out if we don't have a target
        if (!controller)
            return;

        Vector3 targetCenter = _target.position + centerOffset;
        Vector3 targetHead = _target.position + headOffset;

        //    DebugDrawStuff();

        // Calculate the current & target rotation angles
        float originalTargetAngle = _target.eulerAngles.y;
        float currentAngle = cameraTransform.eulerAngles.y;

        // Adjust real target angle when camera is locked
        float targetAngle = originalTargetAngle;

        // When pressing Fire2 (alt) the camera will snap to the target direction real quick.
        //// It will stop snapping when it reaches the target
        //if (Input.GetButton("LockOn"))
        //    snap = true;

        if (snap)
        {
            // We are close to the target, so we can stop snapping now!
            if (AngleDistance(currentAngle, originalTargetAngle) < 3.0f)
                snap = false;

            currentAngle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(currentAngle, targetAngle, ref angleVelocity, snapSmoothLag, snapMaxSpeed);
        }
        // Normal camera motion
        else
        {
            if (controller.GetLockCameraTimer() < lockCameraTimeout)
            {
                targetAngle = currentAngle;
            }

            // Lock the camera when moving backwards!
            // * It is really confusing to do 180 degree spins when turning around.
            if (AngleDistance(currentAngle, targetAngle) > 160 && controller.IsMovingBackwards())
                targetAngle += 180;

            currentAngle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(currentAngle, targetAngle, ref angleVelocity, angularSmoothLag, angularMaxSpeed);
        }

        // When jumping don't move camera upwards but only down!
        if (controller.IsJumping())
        {
            // We'd be moving the camera upwards, do that only if it's really high
            float newTargetHeight = targetCenter.y + height;
            if (newTargetHeight < targetHeight || newTargetHeight - targetHeight > 5)
                targetHeight = targetCenter.y + height;
        }
        // When walking always update the target height
        else
        {
            targetHeight = targetCenter.y  + height;
        }   

        // Damp the height
        float currentHeight = cameraTransform.position.y;
        currentHeight = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentHeight, targetHeight, ref heightVelocity, heightSmoothLag);

        // Convert the angle into a rotation, by which we then reposition the camera
        Quaternion currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, currentAngle, 0);

        // Set the position of the camera on the x-z plane to:
        // distance meters behind the target
        cameraTransform.position = targetCenter;
        cameraTransform.position += currentRotation * Vector3.back * distance;

        Vector3 tempCameraTransformPos = cameraTransform.position;

        tempCameraTransformPos.y = currentHeight;
        cameraTransform.position = tempCameraTransformPos;

        // Always look at the target    
        SetUpRotation(targetCenter, targetHead);
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Apply(transform, Vector3.zero);
    }

    void Cut(Transform dummyTarget, Vector3 dummyCenter)
    {
        float oldHeightSmooth = heightSmoothLag;
        float oldSnapMaxSpeed = snapMaxSpeed;
        float oldSnapSmooth = snapSmoothLag;

        snapMaxSpeed = 10000;
        snapSmoothLag = 0.001f;
        heightSmoothLag = 0.001f;

        snap = true;
        Apply(transform, Vector3.zero);

        heightSmoothLag = oldHeightSmooth;
        snapMaxSpeed = oldSnapMaxSpeed;
        snapSmoothLag = oldSnapSmooth;
    }

    void SetUpRotation(Vector3 centerPos, Vector3 headPos)
    {
        // Now it's getting hairy. The devil is in the details here, the big issue is jumping of course.
        // * When jumping up and down we don't want to center the guy in screen space.
        //  This is important to give a feel for how high you jump and avoiding large camera movements.
        //   
        // * At the same time we dont want him to ever go out of screen and we want all rotations to be totally smooth.
        //
        // So here is what we will do:
        //
        // 1. We first find the rotation around the y axis. Thus he is always centered on the y-axis
        // 2. When grounded we make him be centered
        // 3. When jumping we keep the camera rotation but rotate the camera to get him back into view if his head is above some threshold
        // 4. When landing we smoothly interpolate towards centering him on screen
        Vector3 cameraPos = cameraTransform.position;
        Vector3 offsetToCenter = centerPos - cameraPos;

        // Generate base rotation only around y-axis
        Quaternion yRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(offsetToCenter.x, 0, offsetToCenter.z));

        Vector3 relativeOffset = Vector3.forward * distance + Vector3.down * height;
        cameraTransform.rotation = yRotation * Quaternion.LookRotation(relativeOffset);

        // Calculate the projected center position and top position in world space
        Ray centerRay = cameraTransform.GetComponent<Camera>().ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(.5f, 0.5f, 1f));
        Ray topRay = cameraTransform.GetComponent<Camera>().ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(.5f, clampHeadPositionScreenSpace, 1f));

        Vector3 centerRayPos = centerRay.GetPoint(distance);
        Vector3 topRayPos = topRay.GetPoint(distance);

        float centerToTopAngle = Vector3.Angle(centerRay.direction, topRay.direction);
        float heightToAngle = centerToTopAngle / (centerRayPos.y - topRayPos.y);
        float extraLookAngle = heightToAngle * (centerRayPos.y - centerPos.y);

        if (extraLookAngle < centerToTopAngle)
        {
            extraLookAngle = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            extraLookAngle = extraLookAngle - centerToTopAngle;
            cameraTransform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-extraLookAngle, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public Vector3 GetCenterOffset()
    {
        return centerOffset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make `headOffset` a public variable. Comment/Remove the `headOffset = centerOffset;` **and** `headOffset.y = characterController.bounds.max.y - _target.position.y;` from your `Awake` function.  Now, you modify the `headOffset` from the Editor to whatever you prefer. I haven't done this before and can't confirm that it works.

Comment: Another important variable you should make public and comment out in the `Awake` function is the `centerOffset` variable. Only do this if my first comment did not work.

Comment: Thank you programmer it work's for me when i used second comment

Comment: No problem. Glad I was able to help.